# Prove that $(1-x)^2 (d^2/dx^2) - (x)(d/dx) + (p^2)(y) = 0 $

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I couldn't solve this question

Prove that

$$(1-x)^2 (d^2/dx^2) - (x)(d/dx) + (p^2)(y) = 0 $$

knowing that $y = \sin(pt)$ and  $x = \sin(t)$, $ p$ is a constant

$$dy/dx = (dy/dt) * (dt/dx)$$

Answer (score 0):

$$\dfrac{dx}{dt}=\cos t$$

$$ \dfrac{dy}{dx}=\dfrac{p\cos pt}{\cos t}\implies\cos t \dfrac{dy}{dx}=p\cos pt$$

Differentiate both sides with respect to $x$

$$\cos t\dfrac{d^2y}{dx^2}-\dfrac{dy}{dx}\sin t\dfrac{dt}{dx}=-p^2\sin pt\dfrac{dt}{dx}$$

$$\cos^2t \dfrac{d^2y}{dx^2}-\dfrac{dy}{dx}\sin t=-p^2\sin pt$$

Replace the values of $\sin t,\sin pt,\cos^2t=1-\sin^2t$

Comment: But  (1-sint)^2  is different than 1 - sin^2 t

Comment: @Anttarm, I believe that is a typo in the question

Comment: it is unfortunately not, that one of the reasons the question is so hard